# Regular expression with binary alphabet.

Tags: proof-verification, regular-expressions

Consider a binary alphabet. We want to find regular expression, which determine sequences , where every length of block of zeroes divide by 3.

My attempt : 
$1^* ((000)^* 1^*)^* $. Does it right, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question and your comments, you are looking for an unambiguous regular expression for your language $L$. In this case, just use $(1 + 000)^*$. Indeed the language $\{000, 1\}$ is a code (in fact it is a bifix code, that is, a prefix code and a suffix code).

For each $n \geqslant 0$, let $L_n = L \cap \{0, 1\}^n$. Then the generating series of $|L_n|$ is
$$
  \sum_{n \geqslant 0} |L_n|\ t^n = (t +t^3)^* = \frac{1}{1 - t- t^3}
$$
I let you find the recurrence relation defining the coefficients $|L_n|$, since it was not part of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answer works, but could be simplified as $((000)^*1^*)^*$.

Comment: I'm afraid the answers are different, because in my answer $1000$ counts two times. The main problem to make the answer be without repeated cases.

Comment: What do you mean with "repeated cases"? I could derive 1000 from both your and my regular expression in infinitely many ways. Also, this is not mentioned at all in your question. Please add any and all relevant information if you want to get the right answer.

Comment: actually it deals with combinatorical problem : find number of binary sequnces where every block of zeroes has length divisible by 3.

Comment: It's a completely different question... Also, there are infinitely many: 000, 000000, 000000000, etc.

Comment: that's the problem. How to delete repeated cases

Comment: Please, (1) figure out what your question is and (2) open a new question if you want an answer. I'm not going to guess what you're trying to do here in the comments.